# AspNet Core Add Migration - ConnectionString is from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working with AspNet Core 2.0, I have a situation where I have a context but the connection string is dynamic as per selected by the user at runtime.

Add-Migration doesn't work as it wants to have the connection string to match migration history.

```
var datastore = _MainDBContext.datastores.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.db_type=="MS");
string connectionString = @"Server=" + datastore.db_instance_ip + ";Port=3306;Database=" + datastore.db_name + ";Uid=" + datastore.db_user + ";Password=" + datastore.db_pass + ";";
optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connectionString);
_MSDBContext= new MSDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
_MSDBContext.Database.Migrate();
```

**Error**

No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
[image: Error Screenshot]

I want the migrate to create the database along with tables dynamically. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "as it wants to have the connection string to match migration history". Can you show what kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski - Updated the question with details

Comment: fyi, there is a ConnectionStringBuilder object instead of concatenating strings

Answer (score 0):

The error message says your DbContext needs a constructor which accepts a  DbContextOptions.

```
public MSDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}
```

Or you could try the following approach (inside of your context class):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
           .Build();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("NAME_OF_CONNECTION_STRING");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString); //or any other DB provider
    }
}
```

Of course, you can use different logic to get the connection string. You don't need to use `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the thing here is that I have dynamic connection strings. In real I have a database which stores the connection strings that are dynamically created. So at a time when there are no connection strings created at start how can I add a migration.

In simple words is there a way I can add migration if I don't have a connection string.

Comment: Just read your sentence one more time - "can add migration if I don't have a connection string". How do you want to achieve that?:) To be able to update the database you need to connect that database.

Comment: I know that connection string is required to update the database but it shouldn't be required while creating the migration. My database connection string is stored in db and based on user selection I want the context to be created.